# An unhandled exception occured in 'node_module/terser' ,when I tried to execute ng serve command

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules

When I tried to execute ng serve for a particular angular project in the root folder I got this exception.

Exception:**An unhandled exception occured:No valid exports main found for  'path.../node_module/terser'**

The npm version that I am using is 6.13.1

Is this issue is related to my npm?

Comment: Did you try deleting the node_modules and do npm install again?

Comment: The issue got resolved after updating to the latest version for npm from 6.13.1 to 6.14.13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/terser/terser/issues/819), probably

Try this before you serve again

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

If that doesn't work, what version is your npm? You can find out with

```
npm -v
```